# ES6 rest parameter code not working

Tags: javascript

why is this code not summing?
I'm trying to use javascript ...rest parameter

```
function sum(...nums) {  
  let total = 0;  
  for(const num of nums) {  
    total += num;  
  }  
  return total;  
}   

sum(10, 36, 7, 84, 90, 110);
```

Comment: Works for me---What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: seems to be working fine. try to `console.log()` the result

Answer (score 2):

You're code is working perfectly fine. You're just not actually outputting the results anywhere:

```js
function sum(...nums) {
  let total = 0;  
  for(const num of nums) {  
    total += num;  
  }  
  return total;  
}   

let res = sum(10, 36, 7, 84, 90, 110);

console.log(`Total: ${res}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is great but you are not outputting anything :)

```js
const sum = (nums) => [...nums].reduce((x, y) => x + y, 0)

const nums = [10, 36, 7, 84, 90, 110]

const result = sum(nums)

console.log(result)
```